# If $y'' \leq y$ and $y'(0) = 0$, is it true that $y = 0$ on $[0,\infty)$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

> Assume $y(t)$ is a function such that $y,y'$ and $y''$ are continuous on $[0,\infty)$, $y(0) = 0$ and $y(t) \geq 0$. Show that:
>
> 1. If $y' \leq y$, then $y = 0$ on $[0,\infty)$;
> 2. If $y' \leq y^2$, then $y = 0$ on $[0,\infty)$;
> 3. If $y'' \leq y$ and $y'(0) = 0$, is it true that $y = 0$ on $[0,\infty)$?

1. This is a classic problem: If $y' \leq y$, then multiply the inequality by $e^{-t}$ gives
   $$
   (e^{-t}y)' \leq 0
   $$
   this is a function which is greater or equal to $0$ and $e^{-t}y(0) = 0$, as the derivative tells this forces $y = 0$.
2. My intuitive says to multiply both sides by $e^{\int y}$ so to get
   $$
   (e^{\int y}y)' \leq 0
   $$
   and apply the same argument as above, however I'm not sure if this is valid: there might be something I didn't catch so that this argument might fail.

and it seems like 3 is false, but I haven't found an counterexample yet.

Edit: bountied because the need for verification of 2 and an answer for 3.

Comment: $y'' \le y$  is equivalent to $((y')^2)' \le (y^2)'$ (provided $y' \not\equiv 0$, of course). To see this, multiply both sides by $y'$. I'm not sure if it's super helpful, but it's what jumped out at me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2. You might want to try $(e^{-\int y}y)'=e^{-\int y}(y'-y^2)\le 0$. Or use $(y^{-1})'=-y^{-2}y'$ for some interval $[t_1,t_2]$ where $y$ is strictly positive.
3. Add $y'$ and multiply with $e^t$, then this integrates to
   $$
   e^ty'(t)\le e^ty(t),
   $$
   since $y(0)=y'(0)=0$. One further integration leads to $e^{-t}y(t)\le 0$. Or refer to case 1.